# Unity: Switcher is not showing window previews

Tags: unity

So I just installed Ubuntu for the first time last night, so I qualify as an uber-Ubuntu noob. Anyway, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher in unity, it just shows icons. At first I didn't think anything of it, until I saw some screenshots from someone else's machine that showed full window thumbnails.

To clarify, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I see a collection of icons for the various programs that I have open. If I hover over a program where I have multiple windows open, say the web browser, the view changes and it shows thumbnail images of what the windows currently look like.

Online, I've seen someone have an <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher in unity that shows a window thumbnail for all open windows. This looks way nicer than the icon view, and coming from Windows I would prefer it. I just don't know how to make it that way.

I've used unity tweaks and compizconfig, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: When in `ALT`-`TAB` press the down key on your keyboard, to preview the app. And to preview all the app open, press the super(windows) key on your keyboard with `w`. `super`-`W`.

Comment: That's not what he asked. I've seen videos too where the preview images of windows are the default, instead of the icons. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 12):

I accidentally stumbled on this workaround:

When `ALT`-`TAB` does not display icons of running applications, use `super`-`d` which will show your desktop.

Now try `ALT`-`TAB` and you should see the icons.

The problem re-appears soon, so I have to repeat the `super`-`d` pretty often. A tiny bit annoying I prefer it to rebooting.

Comment: Super+D no longer seems to work in Unity 7.4.0.

Comment: Now it's Ctrl+Super+D

Answer (score 5):

1. *Install* **Compiz Config Settings Manager** and the compiz-plugins-extra:

   > sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
2. Start Compiz Config Settings Manager and disable the Ubuntu Unity Switcher like this:
   **Search** for the **Ubuntu Unity plugin** in the *top left* corner.

Select the *switcher tab* and **disable everything**.
**Note:**  If you don’t disable all the features then you'll have conflicts.

3. Enable the old Compiz Switcher:

Search for the **application switcher** in the *top left* corner.
Finally **Enable** the *Applcation Switcher*.

Comment: Not the best explanation imho but I found it in the end ^^

Answer (score 2):

As of Ubuntu 16.04.1, one workaround is to press <kbd>Super+W</kbd>. This will show what KDE calls a "grid" of the windows in the current workspace. <kbd>Shift+Super+W</kbd> will "spread" all the windows in all workspaces.

[image: Unity windows spread]